# Author page link in comments is different than in posts?

Tags: author, author-template, comments, comments-template

When I `hover` over the comment author link on my `comments`, it shows a link like http://mysitenameeeee.com/?author=24

After I click it, it gets me to `/author/authorname`, which is fine, but I don't want the link to be author=24 when I hover it. If I hover the `post author link`, it shows me the correct link to `author.php`. What is the difference, why and how can I solve it?

Here is the snippet:

```
<a rel="author" href ="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/?author=<?php echo $comment->user_id ?>"><?php echo $comment->comment_author?></a>
```

Comment: How to fix it? Idk if you can change that. Wordpress assigns the user id number to users who have not posted, and uses the user name for users who have posted. (posted ie: written a post).

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/94565/linking-comments-from-registered-users-to-their-profile-pages – do you agree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `get_comment_author_link()` instead of `<a href … </a>`:

```
echo get_comment_author_link();
```

Comment: Edit. Got it to work by adding /author/ in the href. Thanks mate!