# Replace comment avatars and links at the same time

Tags: php, functions, comments, avatar, gravatar

I am trying to replace Wordpress comment author data:

1) **Avatar** (uploaded image instead of Gravatar)

2) **Author link** (link to author page as only members can comment)

I have found a great solution to this from [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/94565/linking-comments-from-registered-users-to-their-profile-pages), and have implemented the following code:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 't5_comment_uri_to_author_archive' ) )
{
add_filter( 'get_comment_author_url', 't5_comment_uri_to_author_archive' );

function t5_comment_uri_to_author_archive( $uri )
{
    global $comment;

    // We do not get the real comment with this filter.
    if ( empty ( $comment )
        or ! is_object( $comment )
        or empty ( $comment->comment_author_email )
        or ! $user = get_user_by( 'email', $comment->comment_author_email )
    )
    {
        return $uri;
    }

    return get_author_posts_url( $user->ID );
}
}
```

The code works perfect for replacing links, and I want to use it to replace the avatars as well. I have created a copy of the function, and changed the names and the return:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'my_comment_imgs' ) )
{
add_filter( 'get_comment_author_url', 'my_comment_imgs' );

function my_comment_imgs( $uri )
{
    global $comment;

    // We do not get the real comment with this filter.
    if ( empty ( $comment )
        or ! is_object( $comment )
        or empty ( $comment->comment_author_email )
        or ! $user = get_user_by( 'email', $comment->comment_author_email )
    )
    {
        return $uri;
    }

    return get_avatar( $user->ID );
}
}
```

However, this function negates the first one, so I get updated avatars, but loose the author links. How do I replace both elements at the same time (avatars and links)?

Comment: Where are the avatars associated? (This is not standard WP functionality, is it?) Anyway, you need to add a filter on `get_avatar` or even `pre_get_avatar`, not `get_comment_author_url`

Comment: I tried that, but when I add `get_avatar` (according to [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/get_avatar)) it doesn't work, the site won't even load properly.

Comment: the get_avatar filter is designed to do what you want to do, while the get_comment_author_url filter isn't,. Perhaps you should add all of it to your question, so that we can see what's wrong with it - why it's crashing your site.

Comment: You guys were right, fiddled with the code again and managed to get it working properly. Thanks for the nudge in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I was burned out from work before, but this morning I took another go at the same code and managed to get it running properly.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'comment_imgs' ) )
{
add_filter( 'get_comment_author_url', 'comment_imgs' );

function comment_imgs( $avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt )
{
    global $comment;

    // We do not get the real comment with this filter.
    if ( empty ( $comment )
        or ! is_object( $comment )
        or empty ( $comment->comment_author_email )
        or ! $user = get_user_by( 'email', $comment->comment_author_email )
    )
    {
        return $uri;
    }

    return get_avatar( $user->ID );
}
}
```

Credit for the original code goes to [Thomas Scholz](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/94565/linking-comments-from-registered-users-to-their-profile-pages) for linking to author pages, this modification retrieves local avatars and two functions don't clash with each other.